# I can't connect to a device that is connected with GPRS

Tags: internet, mobile-network, web-server, gprs

My android 2.3 phone is connecting to the internet using the GPRS network and I get a new IP everytime I reconnect.

So now I try to connect to my phone which is connected to the internet - the internet is working on the phone because I can use the browser.

I also installed a FTP server and enabled to allow all connections.
Unfortunately I can't get even a ping.  It all works when I connect the phone to WIFI (and use the local IP)

So is it just me or is it not possible to connect to GPRS connected phones?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if your network carrier is simply blocking the port. I'd imagine they probably don't want people hosting FTP servers on their network.

Comment: Are you perhaps getting a private (NAT) IP address?  It would start with `10.`, `192.168.`, `172.16.` to `172.32.`, or possibly `100.64.`.

Comment: the IP is 176.6... - I also think that my provider is blocking the incoming traffic.

Comment: Some providers in fact do that. I remember having read so with some "server apps" for Android (in their playstore descriptions) that even the devs have encountered this. I don't know of any public list providing details on which provider does and which not, but asking them should produce an answer. After all, it could also be some "corporate interest" on the customer's end, where <something> should be pushed to devices of their outdoor staff.